# HTML/CSS when height:auto adjust rest of page to fit browser height

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a page with the following code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height:100%;
}

ul.sidenav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top:41px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 17%;
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top:solid;
}


ul.sidenav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: 8px;
}
 
ul.sidenav li a.active {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

ul.sidenav li a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}

.bezeichnung {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    background: white;
    margin-left:5px;
}

.content {
    width: calc(100% - 17%);
    height: calc(100% - 44px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-top:41px;
    margin-left:17%;
    border-top:solid;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    ul.sidenav {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        border-top:none;
        border-bottom:solid;
        margin-top:0;
    }
    ul.sidenav li a {
        float: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    .rechts {
        float: right;
    }
    .bezeichnung{
        position:relative;
        width:calc(100% - 5px);
        margin-left:5px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
    }
    .content {
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100% - 83px);
        overflow-y: scroll;
        margin: 0;
        border-top:0;
        
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    ul.sidenav li a {
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
    }
    .rechts {
        float:none;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="bezeichnung">SomeQuiteLongTextShouldBeDisplayedHere</h1>
<ul class="sidenav">
    <li><a class="active" HREF="http://google.de">Link to some other Page</a></li>
    <li><a HREF="" target="main">abcdefghijklmnopqr</a></li>
    <li><a HREF="" target="main">abcdefghijklmnopqr</a></li>
    <li><a HREF="" target="main">abcdefghi</a></li>
    <li><a HREF="" target="main">abvdefg</a></li>
    <li><a HREF="" target="main">abcdefghijklmnopq</a></li>
    <li class="rechts"><a class="active" HREF="http://www.bing.de">Link to some other page</a></li>
</ul>


<object class="content" data="https://wiki.selfhtml.org" name="main"></object>


</body>
</HTML>
```

The result should be a Webpage where the content especially of the y-Axis never extends the browser window. While the "SomeQuiteLong..." `h1` part and `sidenav` stay fixed 
Like so:

[image]

I cant adjust the height with the `calc` function if the `navbar` is set to `height:auto` and the element take up one/two/three additional lines.
I even tried to solve it with `display: table`.
But that wasnt successful because the navbar stops adjusting if where the titel text begins.
Is there some solution which is compatible with most browsers or can someone give me a hint to solve this last problem.

Perhaps it becomes more clear with this image:

[image]

So while the header + navbar height changes while adjusting the Browser window the content should not extent beyond the browser window (Just the scrollbar gets longer/shorter).

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem.  Can you take another look at the snippet and see if you can't fix your example to work so that we can debug?

Comment: I tried to edit it but the <object> behaves completely different in the snippet furthermore the links are not  working,too.
But actually when running the code snippet there are two scrollbar and what i want is the inner one to automatically adjust to the window height so that the outer is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

To hide vertical Scrollbar for Y-Axis  use overflow property in CSS

`body {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that does not solve the problem it just hides it. Furthermore the complete content is not visible anymore because the least small bit cant be scrolled anymore. I edited my answer to hopefully provide some more insight into my question.